# cURL error 6: getaddrinfo() thread failed to start (PHP - Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, curl, queue, guzzle

Since several month I get the curl error 6 thread failed to start inside my laravel job queue on all my http call.

I understand that it's related with the ulimit variable of my server but even with the ulimit set to 2048 I got this error.

It occurs only when code is processed in the job, the same code outside a job works perfectly.

It's difficult to debug because I can't reproduce this on local and when I push a new version on the prod, the errors disappears (until it come back hour or days later).

When it show up, the error remain for few minutes or few hours or doesn't go away (in this case it need a manual restart of the prod).

Like I said, I've tried to increase the ulimit variable inside my job, but it doesn't seems to fix the issue.

Did you ever face with a similar issue ?

Any help will be very appreciate, I've been struggle with that for days...

PHP : 8.2
Laravel : 10.35

**EDIT :**

The error come from unclosed TCP connection after guzzle http call.
The memory leak and the too many open socket cause the curl error.

I have been able to restart the queue worker after a certain number of job with the command : `--max-jobs=XX`. It actually reset the open connection so I dont have the curl error anymore.

But it's a "hard" fix and I would like to understand why I get this error on this project and not on another that are similar (same http call and same server configuration).

I have added this Guzzle configuration but it not seems to work to force the tcp connection to close after been called.

```php
 $opts->setGuzzleOptions([
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Connection' => 'close'
            ],
            CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => true,
            CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => true,
            'timeout' => 20.0,
            'connect_timeout' => 30.0,
            'allow_redirects' => false
        ]);
```

For information, I use the package [Laravel-Shopify](https://github.com/Kyon147/laravel-shopify) to call the Shopify API and the guzzle configuration is set in the config of the package and is apply to all the API calls.

Comment: The specific error might be a red herring. If things work for a while and this happens then you might have some sort of resource leak somewhere and this error is the result of it and not the cause of it e.g. maybe worker threads spawn but never terminate meaning after a certain point you would reach your limit no matter how high you set it (you just adjust the time it takes to reach the error state).

Comment: Yes, you're right. It was unclosed TCP connection that cause a memory leak on the worker. I have edit my question to understand why these connections are not reused by default by the Guzzle calls.

Answer (score -3):

It's typically related with DNS resolution issues, but it's not the only possible reason. There could be other factors that can cause this problem such as network connection, firewall or other security tools that you've got on your server, proxy, etc.

What I can suggest to be tested first is the network connectivity to make sure no unexpected disconnecting doesn't usually happen.

Comment: Hi @Arashtad, thanks for your answer.
Does only a DNS error could cause the "thread failed to start" error ?

I'm sure this is not a queue configuration or somethings like that because after a manual restart if work (in the job).

Comment: Every answer help me, thanks for that.
I will lookup the DNS, but the code is on a cloud hosting service and it's not really easy to check that.

The network connectivity is good, during the period I got errors (could be multiples hours without any successful API calls in job queue), the same code exec outside the queue does not trigger the error.

Comment: Have you used debug tools like Laravel Telescope or xdebug? When we've no error to work on it's like shooting with closed eyes. If you could generate an error message, we would know what we're supposed to focus on much better.

Comment: I'm gonna install Laravel Telescope, hope it gonna return me a more detailled error message.